# How to de-select a mat-option programmatically?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Currently there is a component that's acting as a menu of fields. When the user toggles the mat-list-option checkbox, a service is triggered which creates a component based on that field in the container of the view. However when that created component is destroyed, I want to be able to trigger a function call that also de-selects the checkbox with the provided field name.
Im able to read the .option._selected event detail when I click the checkbox in order to implement the proper logic, however I dont know how to write to this detail and set .option._selected to false based on its corresponding component being destroyed.

My menu of fields is rendered in this way :

```
<mat-expansion-panel >
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
              <mat-panel-title>
                General
              </mat-panel-title>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <div>
              <mat-list-option *ngFor="let rule of unfilteredRules | ruleFieldFilter:generalCollapsable; let i = index"
                               [selected]="checkboxStatus(rule.fieldName)" checkboxPosition="before" [value]="rule.fieldName">
                {{rule.fieldName}}
              </mat-list-option>
            </div>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use broadcast service to acheieve this scenario.

```
export class BroadcastService {
callbackArray:Object;
constructor() {
  this.callbackArray = {};
}

unsubscribe(name) {
  if(this.callbackArray[name]) {
    delete this.callbackArray[name];
  }
}

emit(name,param) {
 var event = this.callbackArray[name];
 if(!event) { throw Error(name + 'event is not register');}
 event.callbackList.forEach((callback, index) => {
   callback(param);
 });
}

customSubscribe(name, callback) {
 if(!this.callbackArray[name] { 
     this.callbackArray[name].callbackList.push(callback);
 } else {
     this.callbackArray[name] = {
        callbackList : [callback]
     };
 }
}
}
```

Your Menu component file at the time constructor call your subscribe function.

```
constructor() {
      this.broadcastservice.customSubscribe('showMenuCheck', (data)) => {
                 if(data) {
                     /******Your menu logic*****/
                 }
      }
}
```

When destroying your newly created component, you will be able to get the function call in the menu component file by using this broadcast service.

Add this below code in your new component file under ngOnDestroy.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
   this.broadcastservice.emit('showMenuCheck' /**this name should be same as the subscribe name which is mentioned in the menu component**/, {
          yourMenuName : false;
   });
}
```

Comment: I understand your approach and it aligns with my implementation in a broad sense, however my roadblock is in accessing the mat-list-option attribute and setting it to false programmatically.